# input 2 variables(user input by "Buffered Reader") to be pass to a class?

Tags: java, class, bufferedreader

i am a beginner at java language and i use "text pad". i have a problem with my simple program. my task is to input 2 values and show the "sum","difference","product" and "quotient" altogether. (simple right?) in which , here below is the class that supposed to be doing the job of arithmetic. in which is "correct" as i compiled.

```
public class mathclass
{

    int x;
    int y;
    int total;


    void add ()
    {
        total = x+y;
    }

    void sub ()
    {
        total = x-y;
    }

    void multi ()
    {
        total = x*y;
    }

    void div ()
    {
        total = x/y;
    }

}
```

And here is the main program that supposed to be the input and output of the program.
my problem here is that i can't pass the 2 variables (num1 and num2) to "mathclass"
i did research on how to pass 2 variables to a another class. but there is nothing same to mine that i have. i did use some like the putting "private or public" on the variables.
 my teacher said to use the BufferedReader for input. and i am having a hard time how to get this program right. (sorry if i had wrong english(if i am wrong. ))

```
import java.io.*;
public class mathmain
{

    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
    {


        mathclass math1 = new mathclass();

        System.out.print("Enter 1st Number :");
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.print("Enter 2nd Number :");
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(" ");

        math1.add();
        {
            System.out.print("Sum : ");
            System.out.println(math1.total);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        math1.sub();
        {
            System.out.print("Difference : ");
            System.out.println(math1.total);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");

        math1.multi();
        {
            System.out.print("Product : ");
            System.out.println(math1.total);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        math1.div();
        {
            System.out.print("Quotient : ");
            System.out.println(math1.total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two very different problems are using a BufferedReader to get values from user to program, and to get values from your main method to the class is doing the work. As @aioobe says, yo must pass these values. Otherwise this x and y fields in the created object remain with default initial values (0) and nothing happens. I mean. If you don't say: *let the x field in the math1 object have the value of num1 recently obtained value* it won't magically do that.

Comment: my problem is that i did not know how to pass them. my teacher did not teach me how to do pass values. but now everything is okay. what i am missing is an to set up an agruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. (Why doesn't `add` take two arguments for instance?)

Perhaps your after something like this:

```
// Set up arguments
math1.x = num1;
math1.y = num2;

// Perform the add.
math1.add();
// {                <-- brace completely useless.

// Print the result
System.out.print("Sum : ");
System.out.println(math1.total);
// }                <-- brace completely useless.
```

However, I would encourage you to **use return values** and **use parameters**:

```
class MathClass {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    ...
}
```

and then use the class like

```
int sum = math1.add(num1, num2);

System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: ill do that thank you, but do i have to re-do the whole program? i'am not that good with java sorry.

Comment: Well, yes. You'll pretty much have to redo the whole program. Get used to it... I've been forced to throw away tens of thousands of lines of code from time to time. (and I'm quite good with Java ;-)

Comment: but i did place the "arguments" at mathmain below "math1.add(); (as i saw on your guide.) and it did run. displayed correctly. i had flaws on doing the program. there's more i need to learn. thank you for the help :)

Comment: Note also that you can read integers from the user by doing `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); num1 = s.nextInt(); num2 = s.nextInt();`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take some look on how to code in Java because you're going the wrong way.

Either you create a constructor to initialize x & y either you put them in the method add(x,y) which would lead you to make the method static and remove references of x & y from the class. Same goes for the total that should be the return of your function.

Comment: constructor? sorry, what you mean by that? and what code would i place on the program?

Comment: @LCkniGhT http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html You should at least read the basics of Object Oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Use Two Parameter Constructor for mathmain class...**

```
public mathmain(int x, int y){

this.x = x;
this.y = y;


}
```

Please use Uppercase for the Fist alphabet of the class name (eg: MathMain),

and yes, use Camel Case for writing Class, Variables, Method,etc Names in java.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're beginning, I will not point out the design flaws. Your problem comes from how you are using your read values. You read values into num1 and num2, but you never set them in your mathclass object:
`math1.x = num1;`
`math1.y = num2;`
As per what aioobe said, you should look at java design rules to help you create robust, useful classes. I would also encourage you to **encapsulate** your classes and use **parameters** and **return values** whenever possible.

Good luck in learning java, and I hope this helped!

Comment: thank you because i gone to basic with java and i move to Object oriented programming. and this is the 1st program. that i gone too difficult to get with right now.

Comment: thank you. that's the code that i dont know how to use. thanks a lot it helped :)